# How to get SelectedRow in ReactiveTableViewController and navigate to next controller

Tags: c#, reactiveui

At the moment I'm having a ReactiveTableViewController that is bound to ReactiveCell with ReactiveUI. That is linked together in the following manner.

```
public class ServicesView : ReactiveTableViewController<ServicesViewModel> {
public ServicesView() : base()
{
}

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    SetUpUserInterface();

    SetTableViewProperties();

    this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
    {
        TableView.Delegate = this;
        this.TableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(RxCell.Nib, RxCell.Key);
        //this.WhenAnyValue(view => view.ViewModel.Services).BindTo<ServiceEntryModel, RxCell>(this.TableView, RxCell.Key, 50, null); // does not work
        TableView.Source = new ReactiveTableViewSource<ServiceEntryModel>(TableView, ViewModel.Services, RxCell.Key, 50f, null); // also not working
    }
}}
```

When overriding the following the Console.WriteLine will never getting called when selecting a row in the UITableView, does anyone can explain me why this is happening? Would be much appreciated, thank you for reading.

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
     base.RowSelected(tableView, indexPath);

     Console.WriteLine("Hi StackOverflow");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding the data to the TableView, a new TableViewSource is being assigned to the TableView, this is a `ReactiveTableViewSource<TSource>` which has an `ElementSelected` observable. You can subscribe to this observable to get notified on selected element changes.

So you have the option to cast the TableView.Source to `ReactiveTableViewSource<TSource>` and subscribe to `ElementSelected` yourself. Or you can supply an `initSource` delegate to your binding:

`source => source.ElementSelected.Subscribe(OnElementSelected)`

In addition, the `object` returned from this observable is actually the element at the corresponding index in the source data.